# Route Calculation not showing route from current position

Tags: android, routes, navigation, skmaps, skobbler-maps

I am using skmap's calculateroutewithpoints but I am not able to get the route from the current position.

How can I set the start and end point while calculating routes with points(SKPosition)?

Comment: Please attach the code & input parameters you are using so that we can replicate and validate

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using SKPosition use SkViaPoints:

```
SKRouteSettings skrouteSetting = new SKRouteSettings();
skrouteSetting.setStartCoordinate(new SKCoordinate(77.597231,12.973654));
        skrouteSetting.setDestinationCoordinate(new SKCoordinate(77.614500, 13.009965));
        skrouteSetting.setRouteMode(SKRouteSettings.SKRouteMode.CAR_FASTEST);
        skrouteSetting.setNoOfRoutes(1);
        viaPointList = new ArrayList<SKViaPoint>();
viaPointList.add(new SKViaPoint(i+1000,newSKCoordinate(77.629580,13.020566));
viaPointList.add(new SKViaPoint(i+1000,newSKCoordinate(77.622440,13.037359));
skrouteSetting.setViaPoints(viaPointList);
        skrouteSetting.setRouteExposed(true);
        SKRouteManager.getInstance().setRouteListener(this);
        SKRouteManager.getInstance().calculateRoute(skrouteSetting);
```

If you are using SKMaps Version 2.5.1 use the same format of Latitude & Longitude & if you are using 3.0 and above just reverse the latitude & longitude values and you can see your routes along with Multiple Via Points.